# I want ask about opencart to remove footer nav img was there

Tags: php, html, jquery, themes, opencart-module

[it's a problem I m facing in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zbFG.jpg)

I want to know that how can I remove this brand text from footer nav ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Log Into Your Opencart Admin
2. Left side menu click on CATALOG to unfold options
3. Under Catalog click on INFORMATION
4. On right side, you will see all the texts you have under the INFROMATION section in the footer. Select the BRANDS and aither EDIT or DELETE it.

Comment: It is not necessary to delete at all. You can simply disable it or uncheck the box Bottom.